# Compiling parts of Festival code written in C++ in a stand-alone C++ program

Tags: c++, compilation, festival

I am trying to use selective parts of the `Festival` code (written in C++) and trying to use them in my own `C++` programs. Note that this question is not about using the Festival API but about functions within `Festival` that can be used directly.

The program I wrote takes in a `C++` style `string` and tries to initialize an object of type `EST_String` (an internal implementation of the String class in Festival). I then try to print the object.

The code I have:

```
/*EST_String is a string implementation for the festival project.
 * This program simply takes in a C++-style string and returns an EST_String. 
 * This program is being used to test for makefiles etc.
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <EST_String.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if(argc != 2) {
    cout << "Correct usage: <binary> <string>" << endl;
    exit(5);
  }

  string word(argv[1]);
  EST_String e(word.c_str());  //init EST_String.

  cout << "C++ String = " << word << endl;
  cout << "EST_String = ";
  cout << e;

  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to compile it (from the command line directly (no makefile at present)) like so:

```
g++ -I../../speech_tools/include -I../../speech_tools/base_class/string -L../../speech_tools/lib/ -lestbase -lncurses -lasound -leststring -lestools usingESTString.C -o usingESTString
```

The error I get is:

```
/tmp/cczyGTfm.o: In function `main':
usingESTString.C:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `EST_String::EST_String(char const*)'
/tmp/cczyGTfm.o: In function `EST_Chunk::operator--()':
usingESTString.C:(.text._ZN9EST_ChunkmmEv[EST_Chunk::operator--()]+0x3e): undefined reference to `EST_Chunk::~EST_Chunk()'
usingESTString.C:(.text._ZN9EST_ChunkmmEv[EST_Chunk::operator--()]+0x49): undefined reference to `EST_Chunk::operator delete(void*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I get the code to compile properly? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try putting the libraries you link with last on the command line, especially after the source file.

Comment: @Joachim: Yeah. That was the problem. Why dont you make your comment into an answer and I will accept it as correct. A small explanation would also be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the libraries you link with last on the line.

The linker often resolves references kind of "backwards", meaning that the order of files presented on the command line is important: It wants files containing references first, then the libraries containing those references.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to end of your g++ link command: `-I/usr/include/festival 
-I/usr/include/speech_tools -I/usr/include/boost -lFestival -lestools 
-lestbase -leststring`

Making sure that the festival and speech_tools headers directory lives at: `/usr/include`

```
cd /usr/include
ls festival
ls speech_tools
```

I am trying to rebuild cogita with festival support, and my program linked successfully after compiling the object files using this line

`g++ -Wall -fPIC -Wno-variadic-macros -fopenmp -std=gnu++0x -O2 -g -fstack-protector  cogitaconfig.o  go-irc.o  irc.o  whirr-sockets.o -o cogIRCProgram
 -rdynamic /usr/local/lib/libcogutil.so -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib 
-I/usr/include/festival -I/usr/include/speech_tools -I/usr/include/boost 
-lFestival -lestools -lestbase -leststring`

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to link to festival's API too, and the Makefile I wrote executes the following link command

```
g++ -lpthread build/fetch/festival/src/lib/libFestival.a  build/fetch/speech_tools/lib/libestools.a  build/fetch/speech_tools/lib/libestbase.a build/fetch/speech_tools/lib/libeststring.a -lcurses -ldl -lm -lstdc++ build/test/speaker.o build/common/message-queue.o build/speaker/speaker-public.o build/fetch/festival/src/lib/libFestival.a -o build/bin/speaker-test
```

and I get a huge (25k lines) linker error full of undefined references (a part of which is here: http://pastebin.com/PCyV8xAH).  I can assert that the *.a files exist (though I'm not sure if they've been built correctly or not).  I compile speech_tools with `make -j7` and festival with `make`.

Any suggestions?

I'm running Debian wheezy.